# How can we derive 01* from 0+01*?

Tags: regular-expressions

I am currently learning about regular expression and has recently found this question: 
Applying algebraic laws for regular expressions to demonstrate how 01* can be derived from 0 + 01*.

My answer is: 
0+01* = 0(ε+1*) 
Multiplying 0 by ε gives you ε.
Multiplying 0 by 1* gives you 01*
Therefore, 0+01* = 0(ε+1*) = 01*

Is it correct? If not, can someone please explain to me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It’s correct apart from a typo: I’m sure that you meant to say that multiplying $0$ by $\varepsilon$ gives you $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for the answer! but I don't think there's anything wrong with my "Multiplying 0 by ε gives you ε." Care to elaborate? Is it because the font makes it looks like an 'o'? Cheers!

Comment: Oops: I inadvertently copied your error. I meant to write that multiplying $0$ by $\epsilon$ gives you $0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see. So, does it mean the final answer is still 0 + 01* = 0(ε+1*) = 01* ?

Comment: Yes, everything was fine except that one line, which should read: Multiplying $0$ by $\epsilon$ gives you $0$. This is both true and what you need in order to justify the calculation $$0+01^*=0\epsilon+01^*=0(\epsilon+1^*)=01^*\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well, thanks for that clarification! Have a nice day :)

Comment: @LeonardoVinsen: A small supplement regarding $0\varepsilon=0$. Just keep in mind that $0$ is a symbol and not a number and multiplication is in fact concatenation. Since the empty word $\varepsilon$ is the neutral element regarding concatenation(multplication) $0\varepsilon=0$ should become more plausible.